# XmlSerializer.Serialize Stripping the <xml> tag

Tags: c#

I am trying to get communicate to a payment processor. When I use `XmlSerializer.Serialize` 
on my object I get

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>
<txn xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">
  <ssl_merchant_id>xxxxxx</ssl_merchant_id>
  <ssl_user_id>xxxxxx</ssl_user_id>
  <ssl_pin>xxxxxx</ssl_pin>
  <ssl_test_mode>True</ssl_test_mode>
  <ssl_transaction_type>ccavsonly</ssl_transaction_type>
  <ssl_card_number>4111111111111111</ssl_card_number>
  <ssl_exp_date>0612</ssl_exp_date>
  <ssl_avs_address>101 Main St.</ssl_avs_address>
  <ssl_avs_zip>90210</ssl_avs_zip>
</txn>
```

Prior to using that method, I manually built the XML for testing and this worked:

```
<txn>
  <ssl_merchant_id>xxxxxx</ssl_merchant_id>
  <ssl_user_id>xxxxxx</ssl_user_id>
  <ssl_pin>xxxxxx</ssl_pin>
  <ssl_test_mode>True</ssl_test_mode>
  <ssl_transaction_type>ccavsonly</ssl_transaction_type>
  <ssl_card_number>4111111111111111</ssl_card_number>
  <ssl_exp_date>0612</ssl_exp_date>
  <ssl_avs_address>101 Main St.</ssl_avs_address>
  <ssl_avs_zip>90210</ssl_avs_zip>
</txn>
```

How would I go about stripping out the `<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>` and `xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">` from the XML or not have the serializer generate it to begin with?

My object looks like:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="txn")]
public class AvsTransmission
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string ssl_merchant_id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string ssl_user_id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string ssl_pin { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string ssl_test_mode { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string ssl_transaction_type { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string ssl_card_number { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string ssl_exp_date { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string ssl_avs_address { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string ssl_avs_zip { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

My first answer was only half of the problem, you also have to remove the declaration as has been mentioned.

Here is an example:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms, settings);

XmlSerializerNamespaces names = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
names.Add("", "");

XmlSerializer cs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Cat));

cs.Serialize(writer, new Cat { Lives = 9 }, names);

ms.Flush();
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
var xml = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

The string `xml` now contains:

```
<cat><Lives>9</Lives></cat>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at it tomorrow.

Comment: Technically, adding an empty prefix and namespace like that is not supported (i.e., "undefined behavior").

Comment: @JeffMercado then how to get NO namespaces?

Answer (score 5):

First function convert object to xml string, the second one convert object and write xml to file simultaneously.

```
    public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)
    {
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
        var writer = new StringWriter();
        XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(writer, settings);

        XmlSerializerNamespaces names = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        names.Add("", "");

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, names);
        var xml = writer.ToString();
        return xml;
    }

    public static void Serialize<T>(T obj, string filepath)
    {
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
        var writer = new StreamWriter(filepath);
        XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(writer, settings);

        XmlSerializerNamespaces names = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        names.Add("", "");

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, names);
    }
```

Actually I realized that code repeat yourself. In these methods, change only one thing which is writer object, so the code must be like below. In these way, you can easily use code just by changing writer object type.

```
    public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)
    {
        var writer = new StringWriter();
        Serialize<T>(obj,writer);
        var xml = writer.ToString();
        return xml;
    }

    public static void Serialize<T>(T obj, string filepath)
    {
        var writer = new StreamWriter(filepath);
        Serialize<T>(obj,writer);
    }

    public static void Serialize<T>(T obj, TextWriter writer)
    {
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
        XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(writer, settings);            
        XmlSerializerNamespaces names = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        names.Add("", "");            
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));            
        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, names);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Very similar to @payo's orignal answer:

If you want to remove the namespace you may also want to remove the version, to save you searching I've added that functionality so the below code will do both.

I've also wrapped it in a generic method as I'm creating very large xml files which are too large to serialize in memory so I've broken my output file down and serialize it in smaller "chunks":

```
public string XmlSerialize<T>(T entity) where T : class
{
    // removes version
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

    XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw, settings))
    {
        // removes namespace
        var xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        xmlns.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);

        xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, entity, xmlns);
        return sw.ToString(); // Your XML
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use XmlWriter there is a setting to omit the declaration
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.omitxmldeclaration.aspx

I'll work on an example, but that might be enough to get you going.

---

EDIT: Here's a sample that runs in LinqPad

```
string test  = "test";
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream();
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(strm, settings);
XmlSerializer serializer =  new XmlSerializer(typeof(string));
serializer.Serialize(writer, test);
strm.Position = 0;
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(strm);
var x = reader.ReadToEnd();
x.Dump();
writer.Close();
reader.Close();
strm.Close();
```

Output

`<string>test</string>`

Comment out line 3 and the Output is

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><string>test</string>`

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at it tomorrow.

Answer (score -1):

Just to simplify the soln. of the original problem of removing UTF encoding declaration
here is the code

```
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeToSerialize.GetType());
                serializer.Serialize(System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(sb, new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Indent=true }), typeToSerialize);
```